# "a" element inside "li" element overflows the "li" element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a very simple "no-frills" tab using html & css. For this, I have a bunch of li elements and inside each of these, there is a "a href" element. Now, when i look at the output in IE & Firefox (after setting the styles to make the list display horizontally with proper border and everything), I can see that the "a" element overflows the "li" element. How do i make the "li" element resize based on the "a" element?

CSS and html as follows

```css
#tabs ul
{
  list-style:none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#tabs li
{
  display: inline;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
  background-color: #3C7FAF;
}

#tabs li a
{
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:White;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 18pt;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your code-snippet (html and css) so we can hint you on what to change?

Comment: post the actual html. a vague description isn't enough.

Comment: [This article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/) on styling lists might help.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "#" in the CSS declarations. You've an id="tabs" in you html code which needs to be referenced as

```
#tabs {
    ....
}
```

in the CSS. The rest is fine-tuning ;)

And try

```
#tabs {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

instead of the display: inline;

Comment: I actually had the # in my code. I had to remove it here since adding the # just bolded the text on that line before i added the <pre> tag

Comment: I begin to understand - so you're talking about the height of the li elements?

Comment: Yes, the height is less than the height of the a element. Sorry if I wasnt clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the the display on the li element as "inline-block".

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0):

give style to anchor as

```
 display:block
```

Answer (score 0):

I give

```
display:block
```

to both the li and a tags. Then float the li. You can add this code to make the li enclose the a completely:

```
overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; word-wrap: break-word;
```

This will clear anything inside.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply give your li's some padding:

```
#tabs li {
    padding: 8px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block is a good way to go (as suggested).
But if you want this to be cross-browser, you need to add som CSS-hacking "magic" :)

One very good tutorial on the subject is http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Using the method from that article, you'd end up with the following CSS:

```
/* cross browser inline-block hack for tabs */
/* adapted from:
/* http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ */

#tabs ul, 
#tabs li, 
#tabs li a {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: bottom; 

    margin:0; padding:0; /* reset ul and li default settings */

}

/* The rest is "window dressing" (i.e. basically the tab styles from your CSS) */

#tabs li a {
    margin: 0 0.5em 0 0;
    background-color: #3C7FAF;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 18pt;
    height: 40px;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `display:inline-block` on both `li` & `a` did the trick for me man. Lists stretched to accommodate whatever I did with the links.